# Select choice based on what's selected (Radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

Sorry to bother everyone but I'm in a bit of a snag.  I'm trying to setup my code to select an item based on the country selected and type of shipping.  I can get it to work with just the country but when I try to add they type of shipping it doesn't work and I'm not sure what else to do.

Here's my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".choice").hide();

var isUS = $("#__billingCountrySelect__").val() === '1';
var isNotUS = !isUS;

$("#__billingCountrySelect__").change(function() {
    isUS = $("#__billingCountrySelect__").val() === '1';
    isNotUS = !isUS;
    checkRadio1();
    checkRadio2();
    checkRadio3();
    checkRadio4();
    checkRadio5();
    checkRadio6();
});

$(".choicePick").click(function() {
    checkRadio1();
    checkRadio2();
    checkRadio3();
    checkRadio4();
    checkRadio5();
    checkRadio6();
});

function checkRadio1() {

    if (isUS && $("#first").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#US3').click();
    } 
    else if(isNotUS && $("#first").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#INTL3').click();
    }
}

function checkRadio2() {

    if (isUS && $("#second").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#US2').click();
    } 
    else if(isNotUS && $("#second").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#INTL2').click();
    }
}

function checkRadio3() {

    if (isUS && $("#third").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#US1').click();
    }

    else if(isNotUS && $("#third").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#INTL1').click();
    }
}

function checkRadio4() {

    if (isUS && $(".ADS3").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#US_ADS3').click();
    }

    else if(isNotUS && $(".ADS3").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#INTL_ADS3').click();
    }
}
function checkRadio5() {

    if (isUS && $(".ADS2").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#US_ADS2').click();
    }

    else if(isNotUS && $(".ADS2").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#INTL_ADS2').click();
    }
}
function checkRadio6() {

    if (isUS && $(".ADS1").prop('checked')){
        $('.choice input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#US_ADS1').click();
    }

}
});
```

I know there's a shorter way to write this but this is setup for testing at the moment.  There are a total of 11 different choices.  The first 6 are normal selection but if they select ADS it switches to the choice with that shipping option.

The HTML code is:

```
<input type="radio" name="multiChoice" id="first"  class="choicePick" />    
<span style="font-size:1.8em;">Choice 1</span>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="multiChoice" id="second"  class="choicePick"/>  
<span style="font-size:1.8em;">Choice 2</span>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="multiChoice" id="third"  class="choicePick"/><span 
style="font-size:1.8em;">Choice 3</span>
<br>   
<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="multiChoice" class="choicePick ADS1 ADS2   
ADS3"/><span style="font-size:1.8em;">ADS</span>


<select id="__billingCountrySelect__">
  <option value="UNITED STATES">UNITED STATES</option>
  <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
</select>
   <br><br>

<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="US3"/>US3
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="INTL3"/>INTL3
</div>
 <div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="US2"/>US2
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="INTL2"/>INTL2
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="US1"/>US1
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="INTL1"/>INTL1
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="US_ADS3"/>US_ADS3
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="INTL_ADS3"/>INTL_ADS3
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="US_ADS2"/>US_ADS2
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="INTL_ADS2"/>INTL_ADS2
</div>
<div class ="choice"><input type="radio" id="US_ADS1"/>US_ADS1
</div>
```

Sorry for so much code but I'd thought I'd give as much information as I could to help.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Pls put all your code in a fiddle and show us a working example.

Comment: This `<select id="#__billingCountrySelect__">` must be `<select id="__billingCountrySelect__">` and it's value could either be `OTHER` or `UNITED STATES` and not `'1'`

Comment: Here's my jsfiddle but i't not working for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/mjreno/ag3cwr59/2/

Comment: You're after [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ag3cwr59/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ag3cwr59/3/)?

Comment: yes.  I made the select option change.  I'm on number 4

Comment: I don't undestand what the expected output is. Bring on some clarity :)

Comment: when you select ADS, the choice should change to one of the ADS choices.  So you select choice 1 and ADS you should get US_ADS3.  If you just select choice 1, you should get just US3.

Comment: Q:  why are you not simply using value= and name= properties on your radio buttons and get rid of all the ID rubbish?

Comment: @LShetty, does that help explain what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, here s the newest update for the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mjreno/ag3cwr59/5/ I haven't used values and names that much for radio buttons.  maybe you can help with that?

Comment: 90% of your code can be removed if you simply work *with* radio buttons they way it was intended. Currently they are actually being used as checkboxes! set a common name= so they auto uncheck, use value= values to give them unique selections.

Comment: In order to provide a correct solution, you need to describe clearly what should happen when various selections are made. The existing code is incorrect to the extent that most of it will not be needed once the aim is clear.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, when you select ADS, the choice should change to one of the ADS choices. So you select choice 1 and ADS you should get US_ADS3. If you just select choice 1, you should get just US3.  I'm trying to work on code using the values like you mentioned.

Comment: Finally got back to a keyboard (can't do JSFiddles on an iPad) :) Once I figured out what you actually wanted, the solution is to create an ID selector based on the 3 separate sets of selectors. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the actual problem you are trying to solve, the following will do the lot with hardly any code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.choicePick, #ads, #__billingCountrySelect__').change(function () {
        var id = $('#__billingCountrySelect__').val() + ($('#ads').is(':checked') ? "_ADS" : "") + $('.choicePick:checked').val();
        $('#' + id).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ag3cwr59/27/

It basically listens for the change event on any of the 3 input selections, then constructs a target id based on the 3 selection values then selects that item.

**Notes:**

- I used a common `name=` property on the target selects so that only one will be selected at a time.
- I separated the checkbox to a different selector (an ID now, as it has the same name before as the radio buttons).
- I added appropriate values to the drop down and radio buttons to give the required output when concatenated.

Comment: Thank you.  This works with 12 choices.  I'm trying to do 11.  How can I remove the checked attribute for the choice I don't want ADS for?

Comment: @user4739731: Do you mean the last radio button I added? Just remove it: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ag3cwr59/28/ What would you want it to select instead if you chose those 3 options?

Comment: Thanks for helping but when you select choice 1 (INTL1) with country OTHER after selecting choice 2 or 3 with ADS checked, it won't select choice 1 (INTL1).  It stays checked with INTL_ADS3 or INTL_ADS2.  I'm trying to have Choice 1 for OTHER as the country to be INTL1.  This option doesn't have the ADS option.

Comment: @user4739731: As I said: "What would you want it to select instead if you chose those 3 options?" I can't provide a complete solution without the complete rules :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="#__billingCountrySelect__">
```

Remove the hash(#) from the id in the html, hope it helps.
Also when i tested the code there are some missing closing quotes( " ) for the ids of the radio inputs.

Hope it helps.